# Nginx proxy_pass to http or https different behavior

Tags: nginx, proxy, https, http

Good day! We have a nginx-based proxy with next config:

```
server {
  server_name  proxy;
  listen 80;
  underscores_in_headers on;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  bodylog;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X:Y;
  }
}
```

Backend is an application with first login page access to search after it. So the problem is:
When we tune proxy to IP address of backend (proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X:Y) we get that all requests in browser after login in start page go through nginx proxy-server and we can log them to access.log.

But if we want to use here https://address.com for the same application like that

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://address.com;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
  }
```

we got that only first load of login page goes through nginx proxy, but all other actions there (login itself, search after it, etc.) go right on domain https://address.com (not through proxy-server), so cannot be logged in nginx-proxy access.log file, but we need this!
Is there anyway to change this behavior like with proxy_pass to IP?

---

Additional info: Application deployed in kube cluster, so when I try to reach it to IP requests go to kube-service for app with type LB and then to app. When hen I try to reach it to DNS name with https request go to nginx-ingress-controller in cluster, then to kube-service for app and then to app

Comment: What address do you use to access the site through nginx reverse proxy? Is it possible that the application does a redirect or absolute URLs?

Comment: To access through proxy I use `http://nginx-IP:80`, or I even tried the same config but with 443 and certs for proxy-server, so that time I used `https://proxy-dns-name.com`. With 443 result the same - using address.com in proxy_pass gets first request to proxy-server goes to application, but in address string of browser address changes to address.com and all next requests in browser to app goes around proxy. I added additional info about app to initial post

Comment: Go in the developer console of your browser and check exactly what's happening, or use a tool such as `curl` to grab the headers, to see where the redirect is coming from.